# deleting multiple pointers in one line. c++

Tags: c++, pointers, comma-operator

Does this delete all the pointers or does this just delete the first pointer p1?

```
delete p1,p2,p3,p4,p5;
```

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: It deletes the last one. Look up the comma operator (something Java doesn't have incidentally).

Comment: @john I think it deletes the first one, actually. `delete` has a higher precedence than `,`

Comment: @JavaNewb it is quite easy to test, why don't you?

Comment: @Tushar Silly me for not checking. Still got three votes however!

Comment: @john: You are wrong, it deletes the first one.

Comment: tnks i get it now this wiki explains in in more detail. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I know I'm wrong.

Comment: @john: You are right. Sorry for deleting my comment! You were too fast for me. I wanted to edit it to expand on claptrap's comment: how do you test it, exactly?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is equivalent to:

```
(((((delete p1),p2),p3),p4),p5);
```

That is, it `delete`s `p1` and then the comma operator is applied to the result (of which there is none) and `p2`. The expressions `p2` to `p5` are simply evaluated and the results discarded.

Answer (score 4):

Because ',' is comma operator obviously only the first object pointed to gets deleted, while the rest of expressions is evaluated and the results are discarded:

```
class A{
  public:
    string name_;

    A(){}
    A(string name):name_(name){}
    ~A(){cout<<"~A"<<name_;}
};

int main(){
    A* a1=new A("a1");
    A* a2=new A("a2");
    delete a1, a2;
    cout<<"\n.....\n";
    delete a2, a1;
//...
```

output:

~Aa1

....

~Aa2

Answer (score 1):

It deletes the first one.

The comma operator evaluates what's in front of the comma then discards it.